# Dynamically changing what class variables are affected by your class functions

Tags: javascript, class, object

Consider a class which contains a set of other objects.

```
function Food= (){
 this.apples = 8;
 this.orange = 6;
 this.peach = 3;
}
```

Now, I can create an add function.

```
Food.prototype.add(food){
 this.apple += food.apple;
 this.orange+=food.orange;
 this.peach+=food.peach;
}
```

However, what if I want to dynamically want to add in another thing into food, which food.prototype.add will also add?

The first question is, is there a simple way to add all the objects in the class?

The second question is this: I could have written the code as follows.

```
function Food = (){
this.apples = 8;
this.orange = 6;
this.peach = 3;
this.addArray = [];
this.addArray.push(this.apples);
this.addArray.push(this.orange);
this.addArray.push(this.peach);
} 

Food.prototype.add(food){
 for (i=0, i<this.addArray.length, i++){
  this.addArray[i]+=food.addArray[i];
 }
}
```

This way, if I want to add escargot to the things I want to add, I can simply add it to the addArray.

Is there a way I can make a similar addSet, or a addObject. So instead of an having an array with indexes, I can have a set or object with names instead?

Comment: To me it seems like you're conflating two different structures here. Your `Food` is actually `Foods` containing name and quantity pairs. You're on the right track, although your idea of using an object, rather than an array, seems like a lot better approach. (Here, by "a lot better approach", I mean the only one that makes any sense.)

Comment: You can iterate through an objects properties with `for(var item in obj) { ... }`, although based on what you are trying to do a data structure like an array would be a better idea. Mainly due to if you want to add any other properties to food that might not be a number you want to *"add"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
function Food() {
    this.apples = 8;
    this.orange = 6;
    this.peach = 3;
    this.addArray = ["apples", "orange", "peach"];
} 

Food.prototype.add = function(food) {
    for (var i=0, i<this.addArray.length, i++) {
        this[this.addArray[i]] += food[this.addArray[i]];
    }
};
```

However, I doubt this is a good idea if you are dynamically adding arbitrary fruits. As an easy way to extend your class, yes, but for anything more than that you better use a proper [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a follow up question.

If I want to use a map, I would change this.addArray to this.addMap = new Map(), and then this.addMap.set("apples", this.apples), etc. Is that right?

Comment: Nah, I meant you wouldn't have an `.apples` properties at all. A `Food` object would just contain a `this.fruits = new Map([["apples", 8], ["orange", 6], ["peach", 3]]);` and the `add` method would merge two maps.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can try this also...

```
Food.prototype.add(food){
 for(var i in food)
 {
    if(this[i] != undefined)
    {
       this[i] += food[i];
    }
 }
}
```